# WPF c#.NET 4 With SQLite on XPe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

it's the first time that i ask help here, but i really desperete.

I had developed a WPF Applicacation with VS2010 SP1 in c#.NET and SQLite database. It's really a stupit application with 5 windows. The main one, on startup opens few thread: one is needed to manage http connection on it, and 2 thread interacts with a hardware connected with a usb connector (i used a DLL written in C). The main window has 3 buttons and when i press one of them, a new window is displayed. Every single window has a close button that close the window. When i press a button a play a wav file stored in a folder (I used full path to play wav file).

The image for XP embbeded is made starting with tool PE and made with the right tool of microsoft.

The application is developed on a PC with XP SP3 with VS2010 SP1 on board. The application run on it is working perfectly: i can open and close window with any problem and stop.

On XP embedded, i installed .NET Framework 4 and the installer for using SQLite with framework4 (i did the same on my Pc).

If i run my application on XPe (Q7 ATOM E640T with 1 giga of RAM and 4 giga of internal HD SSD), after 8 time that i open and close a windows, the application stops to work and i got a out of memory exception. i monitored with task manager, and when i got the exception the system is using 1/3 of the all memory.

The connection with SQLite is opened at startup of the application and is still opened till the end of it.

With dependency walker I checked witch DLL are loaded on Pc and witch on XPe and i saw that sometime the dll were with different version, so i copied from the Pc the newst on XPe, but nothing went right.

I installed WindDBG on XPe, but it's not help me.

I read a lot of forums where WPF is "compatible" with XPe, so i did the application.

Any suggestion to resolve my problem?

Thanks